# Is it normal for photos to be fuzzy when the lens is on M even though the camera is on auto?

Tags: focus

I just purchased online a used Nikon D600 with the kit zoom--I think it is 24-85mm AF-S. I took the camera out yesterday and shot maybe 100 photos. When I looked at them on the computer none of them were sharp.

I had the camera on auto. I did not fool with the switch on the lens, which I thought was on auto too, But today, examining the lens more closely, I see that the switch was on M, not AF-M. I am supposing that the fact that the camera was on auto while the lens was on manual focus is the reason for the lack of sharpness in the photos?

I will not have a chance to verify this for a while, hence my posting this here. Has anyone had experience with this phenomenon? What puzzles me is that even if the camera was not engaging autofocus--and I'm pretty sure it wasn't--no focus points, no beeps, etc. (can't be sure, I don't know how this camera operates)--still the photos came out looking like some kind of focusing had taken place. I mean, they weren't just a haze of colors. What is happening here?

Comment: What were you shooting (i.e., static landscapes; portrait/people; sports or other fast-moving subjects; wildlife)? What were the camera's settings (were you in P, S, A, or M mode)?

Comment: Not seeing why there are close votes with no comments here...  It's pretty obvious what is being asked.

Comment: @JamesSnell - the OP has already identified the issue (lens on manual), and merely hasn't had 'a chance to verify this'. Also, the OP seems to expect that the camera will operate itself. It reflects a lack of thorough research before posting the question, especially since the OP knows exactly what to try next, and doing so would resolve their question immediately.

Answer (score 6):

To use autofocus the D600 has two switches which should be set to:-

- `AF` on the body
- `A/M` on the lens (assuming the 24-85 1:35-4.5G lens.)

If either are set to `M` then the autofocus system is disabled.  You have/had one or more of those set to the wrong setting and that will have disabled the autofocus.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the Nikon D600 a fuzzy shooter?

It is when it hasn't been properly focused. So is pretty much every other camera.

Even a stopped clock is right twice every twenty-four hours, so it is possible some of your shots could have been pointed at subjects that were close to the distance at which the lens' focus was set. But without either enabling autofocus on the camera and the lens or manually focusing the lens yourself it won't be intentionally focused on anything.